# what is the class wizard file name in visual studio 2019? How can I rebuild it? It is corrupt

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a corrupt situation in Class Wizard in Visual Studio 2019. When I try to "Add Variable" I get the error "Did not find a dialog class with the specified ID ''".

Comment: [Programming Windows with MFC](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MY26J1R).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid some situations like this, may be you can try in a different way.

From your solution, select "View" from menu and from the pulldown select "Class View".

Then select the respective class from displayed class view, to which you want to add variable, right click, then look for "Class Wizard".

the Class Wizard will be opened with all the required fields filled up.

Then select the "Member Variables" tab, then select the "Add Custom..." and add the variable.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience and as a result of discussions with Microsoft about this issue, we have found that if you shut down Visual Studio, rename your project folder (to give it a new time stamp) and rename it back, will trigger a rebuild of the Class Wizard database.

Comment: I tried it but the time stamp of the directory is not changed and the same issue persist. How can I change the time stamp of the directory in Windows 10?

Comment: What about creating a new folder and moving all contents into it?